# Error while building Next.js application for production

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, build-error, react-google-recaptcha

I am using `react-google-recaptcha` package im my application it is working fine in my development environment, but when i try to build the application for the production it is throwing something like type error, i have attached the image below and here is my code,

```
 <ReCAPTCHA
            sitekey={siteKey as string}
            ref={captchaRef}
            onChange={() => setReCaptchaError(false)}
            data-testid={"recaptcha"}
          />
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9zUX.png)

I have tried to downgrade the @types/react and @types/react-dom version to 17.0.2 it fixed that issue but i am using Formik in my application, and in some places i am using `<Form>` tag from the formik, if i downgrade the version it is throwing error in formik `<Form>` component. Please help me to fix this issue guys.